# Consuming data from Google Stackdriver errorreporting with the java client on GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-error-reporting

We have a Java application running on Google App Engine that needs to process errors gathered on Google Stackdriver.

We wrote some code using the Stackdriver Error Reporting API [Java Client Library](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/client-libraries) obtained as the following maven dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-cloud-errorreporting</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.3-alpha</version>
</dependency>
```

but it seems not compatible with GAE, as it complains for

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Google App Engine does not support Runtime.addShutdownHook
  at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-d6bb19ff7906421f(Request.java)
  at java.lang.Runtime.addShutdownHook(Runtime.java:45)
  at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$Application.addShutdownHook(MoreExecutors.java:223)
  at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$Application.addDelayedShutdownHook(MoreExecutors.java:195)
  at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$Application.getExitingScheduledExecutorService(MoreExecutors.java:187)
  at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$Application.getExitingScheduledExecutorService(MoreExecutors.java:219)
  at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.getExitingScheduledExecutorService(MoreExecutors.java:169)
  at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingExecutorProvider.getExecutor(InstantiatingExecutorProvider.java:51)
  at com.google.api.gax.grpc.ChannelAndExecutor.create(ChannelAndExecutor.java:62)
  at com.google.api.gax.grpc.ClientSettings.getChannelAndExecutor(ClientSettings.java:81)
  at com.google.cloud.errorreporting.spi.v1beta1.ErrorStatsServiceClient.<init>(ErrorStatsServiceClient.java:133)
  at com.google.cloud.errorreporting.spi.v1beta1.ErrorStatsServiceClient.create(ErrorStatsServiceClient.java:123)
  at com.google.cloud.errorreporting.spi.v1beta1.ErrorStatsServiceClient.create(ErrorStatsServiceClient.java:114)
  at com.acme.gcp.errors.App.processErrorStats(App.java:39)
```

So the question is: is there any way for consuming Google Stackdriver errors from GAE, other than fetching data from the REST api through the Google HTTP Client?

*UPDATE*

The error arises irrespective of the *serviceClient* configurations tried so far.

i.e. this is one of the configuration attempts leading to the error:

```
ErrorStatsServiceSettings errorStatsServiceSettings = ErrorStatsServiceSettings
    .defaultBuilder()
    .deleteEventsSettings()
    .getRetrySettingsBuilder()
    .setTotalTimeout(Duration.standardSeconds(30))
    .build();
ErrorStatsServiceClient.create(errorStatsServiceSettings); //error arising here
```

*UPDATE2*

There is an issue for Java gRPC GAE compatibility at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/issues/1490#issuecomment-283597294

Comment: According to this document https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/ you can use Stackdriver error reporting on both Google app engine standard  environment and flexible environment.

Comment: @BravinBalasubramaniam in fact I'd say it should work... maybe it is simply a matter of setting proper executors (for GAE compatibility).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up using another library from Google providing a Java API for Stack driver error reporting:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-services-clouderrorreporting</artifactId>
    <version>v1beta1-rev260-1.22.0</version>
</dependency>
```

It must be properly configured with auth credentials.
In fact it actually issues HTTP calls to the REST services (no gRPC) as would be done outside GAE.

Answer (score 0):

Java gRPC clients do not yet work in the App Engine Standard Environment. This should be fixed eventually, of course.

In the meantime, you could fall back to using the REST-based API, or, in case you are not bound to using Java, implement a small Go-based app (in the same cloud project) which fetches the error reports, stores them away or maybe passes them on to your Java app via Task Queues.

Comment: Do you mean a go-based app is able to access error reporting data? Does it still use gRPC? (Maybe the support is tracked at https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/issues/216 )
Anyway, is it possible to get errorreporting data from another project?